# Yet another 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I keep getting this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in [CENSORED]/add_test.php:93 Stack trace: #0 [CENSORED]/add_test.php(93): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in [CENSORED]/add_test.php on line 93

The code is as follows:

```
    $test_name = $_POST['test_name'];
    $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
    $start_time = $_POST['start_time'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
    $end_time = $_POST['end_time'];
    $teacher_id = $_POST['teacher_id'];

    if(isset($_POST['test'])){
      $exam_mode = "1";  
    }

    else{
      $exam_mode = "0";
    }

    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $max_score = $_POST['maxs'];
    $qtext = $_POST['qtext'];
    $qtitle = $_POST['qtitle'];
    $critsel = $_POST['criteria_selector'];
    $crita = $_POST['criteria'];
    $edit = $_POST['editable_response'];
    $pinnumber = mt_rand(1000000,9999999);

    $start_datetime = $start_date;
    $start_datetime .= ":";
    $start_datetime .= $start_time;
    $true_start_time = date_create_from_format("d.m.Y:H.i",$start_datetime);
    $db_start_time = $true_start_time->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

    $end_datetime = $end_date;
    $end_datetime .= ":";
    $end_datetime .= $end_time;
    $true_end_time = date_create_from_format("d.m.Y:H.i",$end_datetime);
    $db_end_time = $true_end_time->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

    include ('config.php');

        try {
        $cnnxn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("ERROR: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
    $cnnxn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $cnnxn->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
    $query = $cnnxn->prepare("INSERT INTO assignments (teacher, start, end, exam, question_text, criteria, criteria_visibility, question_title, subject, pin, editable, max_score) VALUES (:teacher, :start, :end, :exam, :question_text, :criteria, :criteria_visibility, :question_title, :subject, :pin, :editable, :max_score)");
    $query->bindParam(':teacher', $userid);
    $query->bindParam(':start', $db_start_time);
    $query->bindParam(':end', $db_end_time);
    $query->bindParam(':exam', $exam_mode);
    $query->bindParam('::question_text', $qtext);
    $query->bindParam(':criteria', $crita);
    $query->bindParam(':criteria_visibility', $critsel);
    $query->bindParam(':question_title', $qtitle);
    $query->bindParam(':subject', $subject);
    $query->bindParam(':pin', $pinnumber);
    $query->bindParam(':editable', $edit);
    $query->bindParam(':max_score', $max_score);
    $query->execute();

    if ($query !== false)
                {
                    print "<div class=\"message\">Success!</div>";
                }
    $cnnxn = null;  
    }
```

(I know the date part is ugly. It's just too late an hour for my head to work straight. Been banging my head to the wall with this PDOException error.)

Line 93 is where the script executes the query.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `$query->bindParam('::question_text', $qtext);` is correct :)?

Comment: Try `$query->bindParam(':question_text', $qtext);`

Comment: *Eagle-eye @Matt!* `$query->bindParam('::question_text', $qtext);` is a typo.

Comment: It's what @Matt mentioned. You have `::question_text` instead of `:question_text`. Funny how it even stands out when you look at parameter list :)

Comment: Aaah. :D I think I need to get a good night's sleep before I continue. :) 
That solved it, thanks!

Comment: How do I mark this solved, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference, it was a typo

```
$query->bindParam('::question_text', $qtext);
```

Should have been

```
$query->bindParam(':question_text', $qtext);
```